# How can I prove that $m <n$ then $m^2 < n^2$

Tags: proof-explanation

I'm having trouble taking this test, I apologize if the question is duplicated and I appreciate any indication of content. My math base is not that good, so please be clear.  If $0 < m < n$, can I prove:

$$m < n \Rightarrow m^2 < n^2.$$

Comment: This is false. Take $m = -1$ and $n = 0$.

Comment: Sorry, 0 < m < n. I will editing

Comment: Observe $n^2 - m^2 = (n-m) (n+m) \gt 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume $n > m >0$ because it may not be true if $m$ or $n$ are negative. Let $n = m + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is positive. Then, $n^{2} =(m + \epsilon)^{2} = m^{2} + 2\epsilon m + \epsilon^{2} > m^{2}$.

This is a way of proving that $x^{2}$ is increasing on positive $x$, which may or may not be assumable in your context.

Comment: Thx @Joshua Wang

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if you can consider $n^2-m^2=(n+m)(n-m)>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption $0<m<n$, we have $m^2<n^2\Leftrightarrow 0<n^2-m^2$.

$n^2-m^2=(n-m)(n+m)$

Now $n-m>0$ by assumption and $n+m>0$. So the product $n^2-m^2>0$.

Comment: I had some problems to understand your reasoning, sorry. But I managed to understand after I took the test, thank you very much for your help.